# Could Not Connect - Database or Coding Error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli

We have uploaded the site and site http://bartanwale.gls.in is showing the error:

```
"could not connect"
```

We have corrected various then too.

We have checked every part of code

We have double checked the database.

Please help us with error using firebug we found following error - they don't have to do anything with it.

```
The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when 
prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. When viewed in a 
differently-configured browser, this page will reload automatically. The encoding
declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024 bytes of the file.

<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when 
prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. When viewed in a 
differently-configured browser, this page will reload automatically. 
The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024 bytes of 
the file.


...(u){r=u.arguments?'chrome':u.stack?'firefox':window.opera&&!('stacktrace' in u)?...
```

Please Guide.

Comment: Check logs and temporarily set debug to 2 to see what the error cause is

Comment: To be honest? Read the CakePHP manual. From the start. The basics are explained there. book.cakephp.org

Answer (score 0):

I found this error in your source code, inside the div that now reads "Could not connect:"

**Warning**:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **/home/bartanwa/public_html/bartanwale/trendcart/api/api_methods.php** on line **753**

Maybe you could paste in some of the code surrounding line 753 of the php doc referenced in the error?